# how to write update code vb.net and sql geeks

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I wrote this update code for mysql server using vb.net and its not working.

```
Dim sqlstring = "Update initial_nom set f_name = '" & 
  TextBox1.Text & "',s_name = '" &     
  TextBox2.Text & "',th_name = '" &
  TextBox3.Text & "',fo_name = '" &
  TextBox4 & "',adm_type  = '" & 
  ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() & "' 
    where (app_no = " & TextBox5.Text & ")"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: a) `its not working` is not a good description of the problem b) thats not valid VB code that will compile c) Use parameters instead of concatenating (thats means joining) string together d) this isnt a text message, you can spell out 'you' for the non English speakers e) referring to those who can UPDATE a db row as "geeks" wont encourage many to rush to help

Comment: i have no idea what u just wrote and i didn't understand ur goal .. i am confused

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=my_server;Database=my_db;Uid=my_username;Pwd=my_password;"
Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand()
With SQLCommand
    .CommandText = "UPDATE initial_nom SET f_name =  @f_name, s_name = @s_name, th_name = @th_name, fo_name = @fo_name, adm_type = @adm_type WHERE app_no = @app_no"
    .Connection = SQLConnection
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", TextBox1.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", TextBox2.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@th_name", TextBox3.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fo_name", TextBox4.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_no", TextBox5.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@adm_type", ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString)
End With
Try
    SQLConnection.Open()
    SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
Finally
    SQLConnection.Close()
End Try
```

Don't forget to enter your own details in the connection string.

In answer to your other [**closed**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297581/can-anyone-tell-me-what-wrong-with-my-code) question, this should do what you want:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=my_server;Database=my_db;Uid=my_username;Pwd=my_password;"
Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand()
With SQLCommand
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO nomination (f_name, s_name, th_name, fo_name, app_no, adm_type) values (@f_name, @s_name, @th_name, @fo_name, @app_no, @adm_type)"
    .Connection = SQLConnection
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", TextBox1.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", TextBox2.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@th_name", TextBox3.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fo_name", TextBox4.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_no", TextBox5.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@adm_type", ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString)
End With
Try
    SQLConnection.Open()
    SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
Finally
    SQLConnection.Close()
End Try
```

### Update

I noticed in your other question that you were struggling with ADODB and a connection DSN, there is a far easier way to do this using the MySQL Connector.

Download and install the MySQL Connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

You now need to add a reference to this in your project:

[image: Add reference]

Select *Browse* and navigate to the *Assemblies* directory for the MySQL Connector:

[image: Path]

Select *MySQL.Data.dll* and click Ok:

[image]

Now all you need to do is add `Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to the very top of your form code and you will be able to access your database once you have created the correct connection string.

Here is some example code which will give you and idea of how you can perform some simple operations on your DB, this is tested and working (I was bored this morning!).

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server=my_server;Database=my_db;Uid=my_username;Pwd=my_password;"
    Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            ComboBox4.Items.Add(i)
        Next
        ComboBox4.SelectedIndex = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub update_row()
        Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        With SQLCommand
            .CommandText = "UPDATE nomination SET f_name =  @f_name, s_name = @s_name, th_name = @th_name, fo_name = @fo_name, adm_type = @adm_type WHERE app_no = @app_no"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", TextBox1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@th_name", TextBox3.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fo_name", TextBox4.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_no", TextBox5.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@adm_type", ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString)
        End With
        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub insert_row()
        Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand()
        With SQLCommand
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO nomination (f_name, s_name, th_name, fo_name, app_no, adm_type) values (@f_name, @s_name, @th_name, @fo_name, @app_no, @adm_type)"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", TextBox1.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_name", TextBox2.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@th_name", TextBox3.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@fo_name", TextBox4.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@app_no", TextBox5.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@adm_type", ComboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString)
        End With
        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub select_from()
        Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim SQLAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim DTable As New DataTable
        With SQLCommand
            .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM nomination"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
        End With
        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLAdapter.SelectCommand = SQLCommand
            SQLAdapter.Fill(DTable)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DTable
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub create_table()
        Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand
        With SQLCommand
            .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE nomination (f_name varchar(50),s_name varchar(50),th_name varchar(50),fo_name varchar(50),app_no varchar(50),adm_type varchar(50))"
            .Connection = SQLConnection
        End With
        Try
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        Finally
            SQLConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub drop_table()
        If MsgBox("Are you really sure you want to DROP this table?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand
            With SQLCommand
                .CommandText = "DROP TABLE nomination"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub truncate_table()
        If MsgBox("Are you really sure you want to TRUNCATE this table?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Dim SQLCommand As New MySqlCommand
            With SQLCommand
                .CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE nomination"
                .Connection = SQLConnection
            End With
            Try
                SQLConnection.Open()
                SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
            Finally
                SQLConnection.Close()
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        create_table()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        drop_table()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        insert_row()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        update_row()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        select_from()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        truncate_table()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here's the form I used, it needs Button1 - Button6, TextBox1 - TextBox5, ComboBox4 and a DataGridView control.

[image: Form1]

Hope this helps you out.